# How can I append to a many-to-many relation in Gorm without upserting the already-existing associated rows?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

How can I associate a model with already-existing other models in a many-to-many association without having GORM execute queries to UPSERT the already-existing models?

Example:

Suppose I have two GORM models in a many-to-many association with each other:

```
type A struct {
    ID int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Bs []B `gorm:"many2many:a_bs;"`
}

type B struct {
    ID int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    As []A `gorm:"many2many:a_bs;"`
}
```

Suppose I create two As:

```
a1 := A{}
db.Create(&a1)

a2 := A{}
db.Create(&a2)
```

This will result in the following queries as expected:

```
INSERT INTO "as" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
INSERT INTO "as" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

And suppose I then want to create a B and associate it with the As:

```
b := B{
    As: []A{a1, a2},
}
db.Create(&b)
```

This will result in the following queries:

```
INSERT INTO "as" ("id") VALUES (3),(4) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "id"
INSERT INTO "a_bs" ("b_id","a_id") VALUES (3,3),(3,4) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
INSERT INTO "bs" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

How can I eliminate the first query, which unnecessarily upserts the already-inserted A models?

Using

```
b := B{}
db.Create(&b)
db.Model(&b).Association("As").Append([]A{a1, a2})
```

for the second bit of code instead has the same effect. Adding Omit("As") clauses will cancel the entire insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```golang
db.Omit("As.*").Create(&b)
```

There is a note on the gorm [Associations : Skip Auto Create/Update](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html) docs which details this. It's easy to miss.