# gorm many2many creates on associated table instead of intermediate one

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using the gorm framekwork with a postgresql database. I defined following two models:

```
type A struct {
  ID int
  Name string
  Bs `gorm:"many2many:a_b;"`
}

type B struct {
  Value string
  Type string
}
```

I setup on startup the auto migrate for these two:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&A{}, &B{})
```

then I want to create a new entry of type A and a bunch of relations to objects B in the same action:

```
var desiredBs []*B
db.Where("type = ?", "SOMETHING").Find(&desiredBs) // suppose this returns 2 rows of type B that match

db.Create(A{Name: "name", Bs: desiredBs})
```

but these lines create two new rows in table B and creates the desired two rows in table a_b.

How do I PREVENT the new rows in table B from being created?

Comment: Did you try like it described in the doc: https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Appending-Associations ?

Comment: The problem is the same: it is still creating an entry in table B which I don't want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64253800/how-can-i-append-to-a-many-to-many-relation-in-gorm-without-upserting-the-alread

Comment: In short: `db.Omit("Bs.*").Create(&A{Name: "name", Bs: desiredBs})`

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly I did eventually find it in the docs. I didn't find that question on my search.